# Please move NetBeans question to AU

Tags: discussion

I tried to save a question from StackOverflow. It was closed there, so I flagged it and asked to move it to here. The reply was the following (after a **declined**):

`declined - Ask on their meta. Won't migrate unless their mods ask us.`

Could you guys save the Q&A?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660515/how-to-fix-netbeanss-look-on-ubunbu

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155726/why-is-this-question-about-netbeans-off-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question is already present in Ask Ubuntu.

- [Ugly fonts in Netbeans - How can i make it use the system font?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font)

**Update**

Since that question is ontopic in stackoverflow , I posted about it in meta stackoverflow. And now it is reopened

Comment: @jokerdino: thanks again :)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, why do you want this migrated? Are you still having an issue with it? If so just ask the question again. It's not that difficult to edit the post, ask it here, **edit it** to reflect your current situation. It's already closed on Stack Overflow so you're really not going to gain much by moving it here.

If you want to migrate just because you think it belongs more on Ask Ubuntu than Stack Overflow I'm going to have to decline the request. We have [a lot of netbeans questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/netbeans?sort=newest&pagesize=50) alread, not sure it would really benefit the site to have this one.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators can't migrate questions older than 60 days anymore, so this question can't be migrated in any case as it is too old.